# Cobol scoped terminators

Tags: cobol

Consider the following piece of code. What is the result of B? My question is which terminator does the NEXT-SENTENCE statement affect?

```
A = 1
B = 1
C = 1

IF A = B                                  
   IF A = C                                      
      NEXT SENTENCE                                   
   ELSE                                               
      PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END  
      IF RETKD = 0                                  
         EXIT.                 

B = 2                       
EXIT.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should go to the next sentence, which is immediately after the period following the first `EXIT`.

Hence `B` should be set to 2.

COBOL consists of period-terminated sentences and each sentence can contain multiple statements. `NEXT SENTENCE` works on sentences (funnily enough).

One other thing you may want to consider is the use of `END-IF` to make things explicit.

Answer (score 2):

The value of B will be 2. Always, each and every time, regardless of what happens in the PERFORM and regardless of RETKD.

The IF is terminated by the first full-stop/period, and the "NEXT SENTENCE" will "go to" the line immediately following that full-stop/period.

EXIT in Cobol DOES NOTHING. NOTHING. NOTHING. It would seem from the code that the author (I assume you've picked up a program for "maintenance") expected the EXIT to actually do something. It doesn't. It is a "no operation" verb, like CONTINUE.

This "seems" to be the type of logic (which obviously can be written in different ways) intuited from the indentation and the assumption that the code felt EXIT did something (otherwise the IF itself is pointless, as is shown from NealB's code included below).

```
IF  ( A EQUAL TO B )
AND ( A EQUAL TO C )                                      
    PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END  
    IF RETKD NOT EQUAL TO ZERO
        MOVE 2 TO B
    ELSE 
        CONTINUE
ELSE
    MOVE 2 TO B
END-IF
.
```

And this, as NealB commented, is what the program is doing:

```
IF (A = B) AND (A NOT = C)
    PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END
END-IF
MOVE 2 TO B
```

CONTINUE and EXIT are equivalent and actually interchangeable (although I'd not recommend it, as some people seeing EXIT in the middle of some code, tend to think it does something, don't they?).

For new code, please don't use NEXT SENTENCE and don't use full-stops/periods to terminate conditions. Use CONTINUE for the former, and "scope-terminators" (END-IF, END-EVALUATE, END-PERFORM etc) for the latter.

Try this bit of code to understand what CONTINUE/EXIT do (NOTHING).

```
IF A EQUAL TO B
    CONTINUE
    MOVE 2 TO A
ELSE
    IF A EQUAL TO C
        CONTINUE
        MOVE 3 TO A
    ELSE
        do something
    END-IF
    CONTINUE
    MOVE 4 TO C
 END-IF
```

A = 1
B = 1
C = 1

With the above values, A will have a value of 2 at the end and C will have 1.

A = 1
B = not 1
C = 1

Now A will be 3 and C will be 4.

A = 1
B = not 1
C = not 1

Now A will be 1 and C will be 4.

Then change all the CONTINUEs to EXITs and note the results.

Comment: Due to the '.' after the first EXIT, the OP's original program can be summed up as: `IF (A = B) AND (A NOT = C); PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END; END-IF; MOVE 2 TO B.` Good points concerning EXIT/CONTINUE.

Answer (score 1):

As paxdiablo said it will move to the next sentence (basically after the '.').

Also I woul suggest using Continue instead of 'NEXT SENTENCE' (and using end-if's). Next Sentence dates to the original Cobol while Continue was introduced with the End-if controls

```
IF A = B                                  
   IF A = C                                      
      NEXT SENTENCE                                   
   ELSE                                               
      PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END  
      IF RETKD = 0                                  
         EXIT
else
   compute e = 123.
```

While in the following, the continue will jump to the **compute ff = 321**

```
IF A = B                                  
   IF A = C                                      
      continue                                   
   ELSE                                               
      PERFORM SOMETHING THRU SOMETHING-END  
      IF RETKD = 0                                  
         EXIT
      end-if
   end-if
   compute ff = 321 
else
   compute e = 123
end-if
```

Comment: An unqualified EXIT has the same semantics as CONTINUE (both are no-ops). I would suggest replacing EXIT with CONTINUE in the above example.